# Invalid credentials with Adldap::search()->users()->get();

Tags: laravel, adldap

- Laravel Version: 5.4
- Adldap2-Laravel Version: "^3.0",
- PHP Version: 5.6.30

I managed to make the connection work to the AD, but I can't seem to make the Auth::attempt work.
It will always return false. Anyone got an idea, or a hint?

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $search = Adldap::search()->where('samaccountname', '=', 'tba')->get();
    // this is returning the correct user
    dd($search);

    //'username' => 'tba'
    // 'passwrod' => 'is the entered password'
    //this goes into error part
    if (Auth::attempt(request()->only('username', 'password'))) {
        dd('success');
    } else {
        dd('error');
    }

}
```

'usernames' => [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| LDAP
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the LDAP users attribute that you use to authenticate
| against your LDAP server. This is usually the users
|'sAMAccountName' / 'userprincipalname' attribute.
|
| If you'd like to use their username to login instead, insert `samaccountname`.
|
*/

'ldap' => 'samaccountname',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Eloquent
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the attribute that is used for locating
| and storing the LDAP username above.
|
| If you're using a `username` field instead, change this to `username`.
|
| This option is only applicable to the DatabaseUserProvider.
|
*/

'eloquent' => 'username',
```

ah right and

Adldap::auth()->attempt(request()->only('username', 'password'))

is giving me an ErrorException:
Missing argument 2 for Adldap\Auth\Guard::attempt(), called in /media/sf_www/prm/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php on line 63 and defined<

UPDATE:

I managed to get to the success:

```
if (Adldap::auth()->attempt(request()->get('username'), request()->get('password'))) {
    dd('success');
} else {
    dd('error');
}
```

I can get to the success, the strange thing is I have to use the CN name as user name.
if I use the samaccountname which is "tba" it doesn't work.

More then so interesting is that Auth isn't working at all. Returns False

```
Auth::attempt(request()->only('username', 'password'))
```

I could need some help/introductions here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty straight forward. The function expects 2 arguments, you're passing it one argument. A quick look at the documentation shows the first argument is the username, the second argument is the password. When doing `request()->only('args')` you get back an `array`.

Instead do `Auth::attempt(request()-get('username'), request()->get('password'))`

Comment: yeah, that was a misstake from my side. The code is running now but i still get returned false by.